# Unable to run individual Junit Test class in a Webapplication

Tags: junit, mockito

My project is a webapplication, currently I have deployed it my local machine. I have some testcases written in Mockito, Junit.

When I run the Junit test on the whole project, by right clicking on project , all these test cases run successfully but when I pick up an individual test case and run it I get the below error and test case wont run.

```
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
 java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I have all the required jars of mockito and junit.

Comment: Perhaps your run configuration is different for individual tests than for a group of tests. Use your IDE and check the settings for the run configurations

Comment: Now this error is gone but I am getting the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when I run Junit on the individual file even though I have the respective class in the directory